# Contents of TEXTAREA in a Modal remains the same upon reopening

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a `textarea` inside a Bootstrap 4 modal dialog box as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateTitle" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="modal-title">Update title of ticket</div>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="titleText"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<p id="title">Test</p>
```

I populated the contents of the `textarea` by copying from another element `#title` as follows:

```
$("#updateTitle").on("show.bs.modal", function(event) {
    $("#titleText").text($("#title").text());
})
```

*I have not added code to save changes yet.* I tested modifying the text in the `textarea`, dismissed the dialog and reopened it again. When reopened, the `textarea` showed the modified text instead of that of `$("#title").text()`.

For example, if I changed `Test` to `Test123`, upon reopening it showed `Test123` even though the script code above had restored it back to `Test`.

I put a breakpoint and can confirm that the above script was executed every time the dialog is opened. However, the `textarea` just does not show

Is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is because you changed the **text** of the `<textarea>` on `show.bs.modal` but when you type on that `<textarea>` you're actually setting its **value** instead!

On [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/), it said:

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method

So the fix is to use `.val()`:

```
$("#updateTitle").on("show.bs.modal", function(event) {
    $("#titleText").val($("#title").text());
});
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/158406/

Comment: Mmm... I thought `textarea` was different from `input`. Thanks.